# Tensorflow: Custom Layer in Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am performing research where I created a custom Activation Function layer, and want to incorporate it in a model using the functional API.

Problem is that when I use the functional API, it decomposes my layer into the series of tf.math operations I utilize.

With minimal code,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer
class CustomAct(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
         super(CustomAct, self).__init__()
         # do some stuff here

    @tf_utils.shape_type_conversion
    def build(self, input_shape):
        # do some stuff here
    
    def call(self, x):
        # performs abs((x^3)/(x))^(-(x^3)/(x))


# MODEL CREATION
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3, 3))(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = CustomAct()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x)
```

The CustAct works fine using Sequential, but whenever I use the functional API, it decomposes the CustAct into the original math functions, as we can see from the model summary below:

[image]

I think the problem is that when using the functional API, you pass the previous input, which then calls the call() function, which performs my mathematics. Is there another function I need to implement or something to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Try using just `keras`, instead of `tensorflow.keras`, for your `Layer`.

Comment: Actually, you *should* use `tensorflow.keras` as you should not mix `tensorflow` and "standalone" `keras`. However, you should never use `tensorflow.python` as this is not part of the public API. Try inheriting from `tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer` instead and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @xdurch0, you guys are correct, I used tf.keras.layers.Layer to inherit from and it worked. I based my code on the code available on github, which is why I used those imports. Thanks

Comment: Please include the actual operations made in the call function.